# HTML Video Element not attaching to iOS Shadow DOM

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-chrome, webrtc

I have embedded my camera streams into my **react** webapp (using the [go2rtc](https://github.com/AlexxIT/go2rtc) library) inside a scrollable div, with the following structure:

```
<div class="scrollable" style="overflow: auto">
  <video-stream>
    <video></video> // stream 1
  </video-stream>

  <video-stream>
    <video></video> // stream 2
  </video-stream>
  ... // so on 
</div>
```

I noticed that while viewing it on iOS using both Safari and Chrome apps, scrolling the parent div is prevented while sliding/touching over some of the video elements - as of touches are not being registered.

After inspecting the page using Safari Developer tool, it seems that the video elements that prevent scrolling are missing the Shadow Content element for some reason: [Missing Shadow DOM on Video Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yVn4.png).

The video element that this occurs in changes on each browser refresh, which is very wierd.

I tried playing around with the `pointer-events` with no luck.

Is there a way to explicitly assign the missing shadow element to all video elements using js?